# Asus PRIME b450 plus Wake On Lan

Tags: windows-10, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to get WoL to work on my board. Some specs:

- Asus PRIME b450 plus
- Ryzen 5 2600
- WIN 10 Pro

Steps I have done so far:

- Installed latest drivers for LAN card
- Disabled windows fast startup
- Allowed LAN card to  wake up computer in device manager
- Allowed all WoL related options in device manager -> Advanced
- Enabled power on by PCIe in BIOS

The WoL does not work from sleep nor from power-off states. I'm at loss at this point and any tips on what to check are appreciated

Comment: Did you try a different wake up procedure e.g. by USB or by schedule?

Comment: No, I haven't tried any different procedure. I don't recall that the BIOS had an option for USB wake up, but it did have one for RTC. I may try that later today.